# getting an http 404 error while running the following code for spring mvc..Tell me where is the error and how to fix it?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Here I am running a simple hello world program in spring mvc.Here , I have made a simple form which takes as input two integers and on clicking the submit button it should display the message "i am here" but on clicking submit,it is giving 404 error as "The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists"

here is the controller class

```
@Controller
public class AddController {
@RequestMapping("/add")
public void add()
{
  System.out.println( "I am here");
}
```

here is the hp-servlet.xml file

```
<ctx:annotation-config/>
<ctx:component-scan base-package="com.hp.demomvc.*">
</ctx:component- scan>
<bean id = "viewResolver"
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

<property name = "prefix" value = "/WEB-INF/views/"/>
<property name = "suffix" value = ".jsp"/>

</bean>
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
```

here is the set of dependencies in pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
     <version>4.1.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.36</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and here is the web.xml file

```
<web-app>
<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>hp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>hp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: emmmm  I think  you lost something.  add  <mvc:annotation-driven/> firstly  then you may see  your "i am here" output.

Answer (score 0):

it does, because you did not return any JSP page in this method

```
public void add()
{
  System.out.println( "I am here");
}
```

check in your terminal or log files "I am here" will be there,

> If you want output in the web browser, what should you do now?

1. create a JSP page called test.jsp (you can put any name) in the /WEB-INF/views/ and write something in that web page in HTML format
2. then change this method

   @RequestMapping("/add")
   public void add()
   {
     System.out.println( "I am here");
   }

to this,

```
@RequestMapping("/add")
public String add(){
  return "test";
}
```

and make sure you have correctly made your spring configurations

*happy coding!!!*

Comment: Here, what i want is to print the String i am here on the console but it does not printing it in the console